# Set attr selectively using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Setting all `a` elements on a page to have `target="_blank"` is a simple line of jQuery: `$("a").attr("target", "_blank");`

But what I can't figure out is how to do this selectively. I'd like to set all element `a` targets to `_blank` except for those that have `id="self"`.

So far, I have the below non-functional code. Am I on the right path?

`$("a").attr("target", function(val){if ($(this).attr("id") == "self") {return "_self";} else {return "_blank";}});`

Comment: You are trying too hard. `.not("#self")`

Comment: By saying "those that have id='self'" you're implying that more than one element has that ID, and IDs must be unique.

Comment: As j08691 (catchy name) said, try using classes instead

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this, one would be:

```
$("a").not("#self").attr("target", "_blank");
```

You can always take a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) if you're trying to figure out how to do something new.

Side note: It's invalid for more than one element on a page to have the same `id`, so make sure you do not have two elements with `id="self"`.

Comment: Ouch. That was so easy it hurt. Thank you!

Comment: You can also use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector: `$("a:not(#self)").attr("target", "_blank");`

Answer (score 2):

There is a .not method specifically for the purpose of excluding an element (or collection of elements) from the selection.

```
$("a").not("#self").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) method:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('id')=='self'){
     return $(this).attr('target','self');
  } else{
     return $(this).attr('target','_blank');
  }
});
```

But I would recommend to use class instead of checking id as simple as like this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('self')){
         return $(this).attr('target','_blank');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to do this would be in the selector itself like this:

```
 $('a[id!="self"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```

a more flexible approach would be to use jQuery's filter method like this:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
   return $(this).attr('id') != 'self'; // Returning false means the element will not be used.
}).attr("target", "_blank");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements based on their attribute values. [See this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("a[id!='self']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Refer this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49p0a9ca/1/)

Comment: But that's not really what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Yes, but its just a matter of replacing html with attr and set the target accordingly. Selector is what matters here! Anyways, will update my answer with attr in a moment.